# Automatically inserting Colon (:) in multiple columns under the Options Explicit

Tags: excel, vba, range, dimensions

I was looking for a code to automatically insert the ':' (colon) into the columns R and S, W and X, and found code that I thought I could customise to my needs, but I am facing two issues:

1. The code works in R and S, but also need the code to run in columns W and X as well
2. I get an *error*:

   > Variable not Defined - stopping at **TLen** and I guess it will also stop at **TimeV**

The programmer doesn't use the `Option Explicit`, (it works OK without `Option Explicit`). But all my code is always with `Option Explicit`, but I'm not sure how to write the `Dim` for the two variables.

This code is in a specific worksheet, in the *Worksheet_Change* sub, where I have other code for other things, like the timestamp when people make a selection from column B, it will automatically populate when a selection is made in column B.

I have tried the colon code in another workbook, without the `Option Explicit` and it works without giving errors.

The source of the code came from

*[Excel VBA tips n tricks #12 no more colons when typing time of day, type 123 instead of 01colon23 AM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATxaNbTV2d0)*

I've adapted the code to reference columns R and S in the code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' This code will ADD the COLON for TIME automatically
    ' The code is from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATxaNbTV2d0 (Excel is Fun -
    ' Excel VBA Tips n Tricks #12 NO MORE COLONS When Typing Time of Day, Type 123 instead of 01colon23 AM

    ' To avoid an error if you select more than 1 cell, this next line of code will exit the sub

    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("R4:S1200"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        TLen = Len(Target)
        [![Layout of Worksheet and sample of the columns that need automatic insertion of colons ][1]][1]
        If TLen = 1 Then
            TimeV = TimeValue(Target & ":00")

        ElseIf TLen = 2 Then
            TimeV = TimeValue(Target & ":00")

        ElseIf TLen = 3 Then
            TimeV = TimeValue(Left(Target, 1) & ":" & Right(Target, 2))

        ElseIf TLen = 4 Then
            TimeV = TimeValue(Left(Target, 2) & ":" & Right(Target, 2))

        ElseIf TLen > 4 Then
            'Do nothing

        End If

        'Target.NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Target = TimeV
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** I can tell you the data type but I want you to discover it yourself. Remove `Option Explicit` and then add a `Watch` on `TimeV`. See what kind of type it is ;) **2.** `"R4:S1200"` governs if the change happens there. What do you think you should change here to make it work with `W` and `X` as well? :)

Comment: I understand that you are 'stretching & teaching' me to work things out for myself, and it is appreciative (and I definitely have learned how to see the type (1.)). But in this instance, the 'Type' is coming as Variant/Date, even though it is meant to be time (maybe I am misunderstanding the syntax). 2. but without an example how am I to learn, I have obviously exhausted my search on resolving this, but found nothing .. the reason why I posted the question. Thank you for encouraging me to continue solving things on my own :)

Comment: Good Job! :) Posted an answer as comments will not be able to support what I want to say. My answer is for your reference only.

Comment: What is the meaning "`[![Layout of Worksheet and sample of the columns that need automatic insertion of colons ][1]][1]`" in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the range of the Intersect `Intersect(Range("R:S,W:X"),Target)`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target) = False Then
        MsgBox Target & " is not a number", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Intersect(Range("R:S,W:X"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim n As Long
    n = Len(Target)
    If n >= 1 And n <= 4 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        If n <= 2 Then
            Target.Value2 = TimeSerial(Target, 0, 0)
        Else
            Target.Value2 = TimeSerial(Int(Target / 100), Target Mod 100, 0)
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: BRILLIANT - works a dream, thank you VERY much

Comment: CDP1802, Apologies for the delay in feedback. 
Unfortunately I have come across a glitch with the code, when entering in any time between midnight and 1am (eg. 0001, or 0059) it comes up with a whacko date or number. I have checked the column formatting, which is set to [HH]:mm and works perfectly for any time other than between midnight and 0001am. I have warned the users about this glitch, however, I don't know why or how to fix it myself. I'm using Excel 365 on Winodws 10 (in case there is a known issue with these versions). 
Would you be able to help?
With gratitude, 
TheShyButterfly

Comment: @theshybutterfly Try `n = Len(Cstr(Val(Target)))`. That will remove the leading zeros so n=1 for 0001 and 2 for 0059

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that you are 'stretching & teaching' me to work things out for myself, and it is appreciative (and I definitely have learned how to see the type (1.)). But in this instance, the 'Type' is coming as Variant/Date, even though it is meant to be time (maybe I am misunderstanding the syntax). – TheShyButterfly

You did well! Yes, that is one way to find the type. The other way is to use the [VarType function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim TimeA

    TimeA = TimeValue("01:00 PM")

    MsgBox VarType(TimeA)
End Sub
```

This will give you `7` which is `vbDate`.

[image]

[image]

You can also store time as `Variant` and `Double` as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim TimeA As Date
    Dim TimeB As Double
    Dim TimeC As Variant

    TimeA = TimeValue("01:00 PM")
    TimeB = TimeValue("01:00 PM")
    TimeC = TimeValue("01:00 PM")

    MsgBox "Time stored as Date : " & TimeA
    MsgBox "Time stored as Double : " & TimeB
    MsgBox "Time stored as Variant : " & TimeC

    MsgBox "TimeA formated as Date : " & Format(TimeA, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    MsgBox "TimeB formated as Date : " & Format(TimeB, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    MsgBox "TimeC formated as Date : " & Format(TimeC, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
End Sub
```

[image]

> but without an example how am I to learn, I have obviously exhausted my search on resolving this, but found nothing .. the reason why I posted the question. Thank you for encouraging me to continue solving things on my own :) TheShyButterfly

You can write the range as *CDP1802* shown in his post or you can use the [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union).

For example,

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim rngCombined As Range

    Set rngA = Range("R4:S1200")
    Set rngB = Range("W4:X1200")

    Set rngCombined = Union(rngA, rngB)

    MsgBox rngCombined.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

So in your code it becomes `Intersect(rngCombined, Target) Is Nothing`.

Also since you are working with `Worksheet_Change` and `Events`, I recommend seeing [Working with Worksheet_Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure).